# jquery file upload plugin - custom message to div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file, upload

I am using the jquery file upload plugin from https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options and have it working for the most part as desired. What I would like to do now is make an ajax call once the upload is compelted. I will then take the data from that ajax call and display the result through a results div. I can't seem to get it to work....

HTML:

```
<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
<span>Select Photo 1</span>
<!-- The file input field used as target for the file upload widget -->
<input id="vPhoto1" type="file" name="vPhoto1">
</span>

<!-- The global progress bar -->
<div id="progress" class="progress progress-striped">
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>
</div>
<!-- The container for the uploaded files -->
<div id="files" class="files"></div>

<!-- message should populate from process.php -->
<div id="results"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
'use strict';
// Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
var url = 'process.php';
$('#photo').fileupload({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
        });
    },
    progressall: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        );
    }
}).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
.parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
```

And I've also tried using the callback to .bind it to no avail as well.

Simply put, I want to upload the file, once it's done and the progress bar is at 100% I then want to make an ajax call to a php page and display the content to a div.

Comment: I don't see any ajax call in your code.

Comment: fileupload({}) handles the AJAX I do believe. OP: Are you actually getting any responses from the server? What does a network monitor show?

Comment: Hello, according to the plugin's documentation I should be able to use various callbacks. The one I've tried is                .bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {/* ... */}) to no avail. Ohgodwhy, the call does happen and is done w/ the plugin. The done:function is what I should be able to use to show it as completed. Again, the images upload to my server and are moved as desired but I am unable to echo anything back from my php code.